# How to pass parameters by reference in recursive algorithms in c?

Tags: c, recursion, reference

## algorithm that given an array delivers the largest number by recursion, but passing the result by reference.

tam: size of array

### first I realized it by value and it worked for me but I need to pass it by reference the result, I really do not know what the error could be, if you can guide me please, since when compiling it, I did not return anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


void search(int a[], int tam, int max,int *result);

int main()
{
    int max,tam=5, result; 
    int array[5]={3,1,5,8,6};

    max=array[0];

    search(array, tam, max, &result);

    printf("the biggest number is: %d",result);
    return 0;

}


void search(int a[], int tam, int max, int *result )
{   
    if(tam==1)
        *result=max;


    if(max<a[tam-1])
        max=a[tam-1];       
        search(a,tam-1,max,result);         

}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Shoudn't you pass in *`a + 1`* in recursion so that it scans the array forward and not the same element 5 times. Also, please ensure that your algorithm has an ending condition - it should *return* when `tam == 1` (or should it do so when it is <=1 ?). Finally, make sure that it works even if the last element is the maximum :D

Comment: Also what do you mean by "it didn't return anything"

Comment: when compiling it does not return the result

Comment: No, compilation doesn't return results. It creates an *executable* program from source code. You mean "running". And the "does not return the result", do you mean that the "program never ends - [it doesn't halt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)"

Comment: does not scan element 5 every time,  by calling recursion with a [tam-1] 
they change the positions and therefore the element

Comment: that's what I mean when I run the executable xd, 
independent of that, here the problem is another

Answer (score 2):

When compiling with 'clang -Wall', you get the following warning:

> warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]

Indeed, in you don't have an effective **base case** and **inductive step** in your function.

I would suggest converting to the following:

```
#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y)) ? x : y

int search(int a[], int tam )
{   
    // base case if last element
    if (tam == 1) return a[0];  

    // inductive case (max of this and following elements)
    return MAX(a[0], search(a + 1, tam - 1));
}
```

Comment: OPs code is/attempts to be tail recursive -- while this is not.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I am pretty sure this will be converted to iteration in any decent compiler, but I guess you are right.

Comment: Then you would be surprised. ;)   Use `gcc -O2 -S` to compile.  https://godbolt.org/g/koZfPJ

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP's code attempts to be tail recursive, and [@Gill Bates 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50207175/8767209) is head recursive, I am showing a tail recursive solution.

```
int find_max_helper(const int *a, int n, int max)
{
    if (n==0) return max;
    else return find_max_helper(a+1, n-1, MAX(max, a[0]));
}

//returns the maximum value in the array of size n elements
//or 0 if the array is empty
int find_max(const int *a, int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? find_max_helper(a+1, n-1, a[0]) : 0;
}
```